# MySQL federated engine "got an error writing communication packet" issue

Tags: mysql, federated-storage-engine

I'm using MySQL federated storage engine for link multiple databases.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html

In my local database(federated database) has a stored procedures to get the result.

problem is when i'm trying to execute the sp it will give this error

`Got an error writing communication packets  1160`

But i execute the sp in several times it will work and few hours back it will display the same error.

MySQL version 5.6.12 32-bit(x86)-(federated MySQL server version not remote servers)

Answer (score 0):

I have personally been having issues with this error when the federated table engine is activated on 5.5.37(x86_64). I have yet to find a specific instance where I get:

> Got an error writing communication packets  1160

The error appears to be random. Luckily (for me at least), I am temporarily using federated tables for a project and will not need them on a permanent basis.